# Confused about how to implement time-distributed LSTM + LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

After much reading and diagramming, I think I've come up with a model that I can use to as the foundation for more testing on which parameters and features I need to tweak. However, I am confused about how to implement the following test case (all numbers are orders of magnitude smaller than final model, but I want to start small):

- Input data: 5000x1 time series vector, split into 5 epochs of 1000x1
- For each time step, 3 epochs worth of data will be put through 3 time-distributed copies of a bidirectional LSTM layer, and each of those will output a vector of 10x1 (10 features extracted), which will then be taken as the input for a second bidirectional LSTM layer.
- For each time step, the first and last labels are ignored, but the center one is what is desired.

[image: example model]

Here's what I've come up with, which does compile. However, looking at the model.summary, I think I'm  missing the fact that I want the first LSTM to be run on a 3 of the input sequences for each output time step. What am I doing wrong?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(11, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1, unit_forget_bias=True), input_shape=(3, 3, epoch_len), merge_mode='sum'), input_shape=(n_epochs, 3, epoch_len)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(7)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1, unit_forget_bias=True), merge_mode='sum'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your question is a bit confused, I'll take the following assumptions.

- You have one time series of 5000 time steps, each step with one feature. Shape `(1, 5000, 1)`
- **The main part of the answer to your question:** You want to run a "sliding window" case, being the size of the window equal to 3000, and the stride of the window being 1000.
- You want the window size to be divided in 3 internal time series, each of these 3 series with 1000 steps, each step with only one feature. Each of these series enters the same LSTM as independent series (which is equivalent to having 3 copies of the LSTM) - Shape `(slidingWindowSteps, 3, 1000, 1)`
- **Important:** From these 3 series, you want 3 outputs without length and with 10 features. Shape `(1,3,10)`. (Your image says 1x10, but your text says 10x1, I'm assuming the image is correct).
- You want these 3 outputs to be merged in a single sequence of 3 steps, shape `(1,3,10)`
- You want the LSTM that processes this 3 step sequence to also return a 3 step sequence

**Preparing for the sliding window case:**

In a sliding window case, it's unavoidable to duplicate data. You need to first work in your input.

Taking the initial time series `(1,5000,1)`, we need to split it prolerly in a batch containing samples with 3 groups of 1000. Here I do this for X only, you will have to do a similar thing to Y

```
numberOfOriginalSequences = 1
totalSteps = 5000
features = 1

#example of original input with 5000 steps
originalSeries = np.array(
                        range(numberOfOriginalSequences*totalSteps*features)
                 ).reshape((numberOfOriginalSequences,
                            totalSteps,
                            features))  

windowSize = 3000
windowStride = 1000

totalWindowSteps = ((totalSteps - windowSize)//windowStride) + 1

#at first, let's keep these dimensions for better understanding 
processedSequences = np.empty((numberOfOriginalSequences,
                               totalWindowSteps,
                               windowSize,
                               features))

for seq in range(numberOfOriginalSequences):
    for winStep in range(totalWindowSteps):
        start = winStep * windowStride
        end = start + windowSize
        processedSequences[seq,winStep,:,:] = originalSeries[seq,start:end,:]    

#now we reshape the array to transform each window step in independent sequences:
totalSamples = numberOfOriginalSequences*totalWindowSteps
groupsInWindow = windowSize // windowStride
processedSequences = processedSequences.reshape((totalSamples,
                                                 groupsInWindow,
                                                 windowStride,
                                                 features))

print(originalSeries)
print(processedSequences)
```

**Creating the model:**

A few comments about your first added layer:

- The model only takes into account one `input_shape`. And this shape is `(groupsInWindow,windowStride,features)`. It should be in the most external wrapper: the TimeDistributed.
- You don't want to keep 1000 time steps, you want only 10 resulting features: `return_sequences = False`. (You can use many LSTMs in this first stage, if you want more layers. In this case the first ones can keep the steps, only the last one needs to use `return_sequences=False`)
- You want 10 features, so `units=10`

I'll use the functional API just to see the input shape in the summary, which hels understanding things.

```
from keras.models import Model

intermediateFeatures = 10

inputTensor = Input((groupsInWindow,windowStride,features))

out = TimeDistributed(
    Bidirectional(
        LSTM(intermediateFeatures, 
             return_sequences=False, 
             recurrent_dropout=0.1, 
             unit_forget_bias=True), 
        merge_mode='sum'))(inputTensor)
```

At this point, you have eliminated the 1000 time steps. Since we used `return_sequences=False`, there will be no need to flatten or things like that. The data is already shaped in the form `(samples, groupsInWindow,intermediateFeatures)`. The `Dense` layer is also not necessary. But it wouldn't be "wrong" if you wanted to do it the way you did, as long as the final shape is the same.

```
arbitraryLSTMUnits = 12
n_classes = 17

out = Bidirectional(
    LSTM(arbitraryLSTMUnits, 
         return_sequences=True, 
         recurrent_dropout=0.1, 
         unit_forget_bias=True), 
    merge_mode='sum')(out)

out = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))(out)
```

And if you're going to discard the borders, you can add this layer:

```
out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1,:])(out) #model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1,:]))
```

Completing the model:

```
model = Model(inputTensor,out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

---

Here is how dimensions are flowing through this model.
The first dimension I put here (`totalSamples`) is shown as `None` in the `model.summary()`.

- Input: `(totalSamples,groupsInWindow,windowStride,features)`
- The Time Distributed LSTM works like this:

  - TimeDistributed allows a 4th dimension, which is `groupsInWindow`.
    This dimension will be kept.
  - The LSTM with `return_sequences=False` will eliminate the `windowStride` and change the features (`windowStride`, the second last dimension, is at the time steps position for this LSTM):
  - result: `(totalSamples, groupsInWindow, intermadiateFeatures)`
- The other LSTM, without time distributed, will not have the 4th dimension. This way, `groupsInWindow` (the second last) will be the "time steps". But `return_sequences=True` will not eliminate the time steps as the first LSTM did. Result: `(totalSamples, groupsInWindow, arbitraryLSTMUnits)`
- The final `Dense` layer, because it's receiving a 3D input, will interpret the second dimension as if it were a TimeDistributed and leave it unchanged, applying itself only to the features dimension. Result: `(totalSamples, groupsInWindow, n_classes)`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I'll get started on trying this out today. The data duplication came to me a few hours after I posted this. However, thanks for correcting some typos and misunderstandings in my question.

Comment: I'm sorry it took longer than planned to get back to this. I hadn't touched the Functional API model before, but I realize now that's what I needed. And I can make your code compile, even testing that the fit function will work with `model.fit(processedSequences, labels)`. However, this only works if labels is an array of (3, 3, n_classes). What doesn't make sense about that is where one of those 3s comes from. If the "outer layer" (the second LSTM, with the dense output) is running for 3 steps, then I would only expect (3, n_classes). Can you explain what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Ooops. I forgot to add the Lambda layer (afterwards I can use an array of (3, n_classes). But the question still remains, how is there are 3rd dimension, and where does the count 3 come from for it? The "outer layer" only be run 3 times, not 3x3 times.

Comment: See at the end of my answer how the dimensions behave.

Comment: Gotcha. I like how you described the dimensions as "flowing" through the model, as it wasn't apparent at first that the purpose of some of the dimensions had changed. However, when I drew it out on paper, I could see what was happening. I happy to report that, with some changes that I didn't put in my question, the test model compiles and trains. But, it opened up new issues to chase down.

Comment: This seems to assume that the output sequence is the same size as the input sequence.  Is that true?  I have an input of shape (batches, 500, 2) with an output of (batches, 30, 1).  I follow this methodology and my model summary shows a final output of (batches, 500, 1)